# Unable to display SQL Azure table definition in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

The error I am getting is:

> Problem loading: The designer encountered an error while loading the table definition

I can view the data within the tables inside VS just fine and can even query the data too. This is a fresh install on my computer.

**What I have tried:**

- Tried viewing the table in both "Server Explorer" and "SQL Server
  Object Explorer."
- Checked if my login credentials has permissions to
  create tables in the "Management Portal."
- Installed SSMS and still cannot show the design of the table
- Tried connecting to the database using OLE DB and SQL Server data providers, but I still get the same issue
- Added my IP connection to the server firewall and turned on "Windows Azure Services"
- Set the connection timout counter to zero

This is the image of my error. I generated a very simple user table just for testing purposes from the Management Portal.

[image: Example of my issue]

This is a simple test to connect to the Azure database without using a project template. This is my first time using SQL Azure just to warn you. Sure I can just stick to using the Management Portal to change the table definition and stuff like that, but I was wanting to keep everything in one program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this on a Microsoft forum after struggling for hours. It still takes an age to load, but with the preview SSDT tools, I did get a visual editor for the first time.

> Posted by Microsoft on 1/7/2015 at 1:59 PM:
>
> This bug has been fixed in the Preview release to support Azure SQL Database Update V12
>
> See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-database-tooling-preview-release-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx for details of this.
>
> The fix will also be included in our next full (non-Preview) release.
>
> Thanks,
> Kevin Cunnane,
> SQL Server database tooling team

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link. I installed this preview release and it worked like a charm! I'm glad it wasn't something wrong on my end.

Answer (score 5):

I have found this issue only applies when using the new "Basic/Standard" tier of databases in Azure. If you switch back to the older style "Web/Business" tiers it will start working again.

Comment: This solved my problem but do we know why? Is there going to be a fix for this?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeHarnwell what version of VS you using? Works fine for me now in VS2013 Update 4

Comment: Hey @KingCronus, I'm using the same version. More specifically:

VS Premium 2013. Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4.